# Filemaker: importing attachments from a mail as references

Tags: email-attachments, filemaker

I'm using 360Works email plugin to import mails with image attachments generated by a website form.

I can import the attachment into the container. 360Works has a record of the path when the email is downloaded and you can then feed that into a container. The path starts file:/var/folders/_l/ - ie nowhere useful.  I'd like, to keep my data light, to use just a reference to the image.

What's the best way to copy that attachment to a sensible place and then import it programmatically into the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export to a new location, were you want to keep it and then re-import it from the new location linking the file by reference. You do not need the plugin for this, just use FileMaker standard "Export Field Contents" and "Insert File" script steps.